# run ffmpeg with multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ffmpeg

Ok i have learnt how to convert videos files using vb.net and ffmpeg. But as far as i know we cannot use multiple threads to run same exe file to convert files. Do you know how i can convert multiple videos using one external exe file (ffmpeg)?

I have not tried because my computer time was over. So iam just asking a general doubt whether if we attach it to one process then wouldn't the process get locked? Then can we multi-thread this application or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on how the external exe (and its libraries) run. If they have a shared component then multiple threads will not work

Answer (score 0):

> But as far as i know we cannot use multiple threads to run same exe file to convert files.

**You are mistaken.**  Multiple FFmpeg instances (1st level OS processes) can run on a single machine.  I'm doing this in Java myself.  You can even use the same source file.  *(Obviously, you cannot allow each individual instance to use the same target file.)*